# Block traffic by process id using Windows Filtering Platform

Tags: windows, tcp, firewall, wfp

I want to block internet traffic by process id.

Is there a specific filter that I can use?

FWPM_CONDITION_ALE_PACKAGE_ID looks close, but I don't want to block ALL instances of a program, just some of them.

I supposed another option is to intercept ALL traffic and somehow eat the packets that are coming from the Process I want to sandbox.

any guidance would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Process ID is not a unique value. Its random value assigned to a created process by the system & may be reused. So filtering by id value may block/allow the wrong process if the process id is reused. You can filter by application path which would overcome the Id limitations & much more secure.

Comment: Thanks dvasanth, the Process ID is unique as long as it's active.  I'm not going to have 2 processes with the same PID, at the same time.  What I'm trying to do is sandbox an process, on demand.  I would like to set up the filter when the process is started, then delete the filter when it ends.

Comment: Resolve the pid to path & filter by path using FWPM_CONDITION_ALE_ORIGINAL_APP_ID.

Comment: I'm still searching for an answer here.  I understand that I can do what I want with a Callout.  Does anyone know of a (ahem) simple callout example that picks up the PID?